# Execute Excel Macro to Copy All Sheets to Master Sheet When Any Cell in Active Sheet Column Changes

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that is executing when a value in F2:F251 changes, but it is not executing properly (or, more likely, I wrote it incorrectly).

When F2:F251 changes in the active sheet, the contents of A2:F251 of sheets January through December are supposed to copy to a master sheet so that new data, or old data that has been changed, will always be current in the master sheet.

However, what happens is that the data in the active sheet gets overwritten and I end up in an infinite loop.  Is that a problem with the auto-run code, or is it a problem with the copying code?  The copy code when executed alone, on command, on the master sheet functions properly.  Also, this appears to be a rather verbose way of performing the actions that I want.  Is there an apparent alternative that is more efficient?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("F1:F251")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Copies contents A2:G251 from each monthly
        ' sheet to master record sheet.

        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Cells.ClearContents

        Dim NextRow As Range
        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("January").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("February").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("March").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("April").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("May").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("June").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("July").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("August").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("September").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("October").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("November").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

        Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("MasterRecord").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        Sheets("December").Range("A2:G251").Copy
        Sheets("MasterRecord").Activate
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set NextRow = Nothing

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It goes in infinite loop maybe because the code is changing the values of the range that triggers the Sub

Comment: How about putting `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top, and `= True` after you're done. This will prevent the event from firing when you change the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the actual question - the reason your code is going in to an infinite loop is due to two reasons:

1. You have not disabled events within the event, so by pasting over the range `F2:F251` you are firing the event again and again and again.
2. You are getting the last row of MasterRecord, but you are *not* using the `Range` on MasterRecord, rather, the sheet the event was fired from.

You must ensure when dealing with ranges that you use the range of the worksheet you expect. Since all worksheets are really just objects, calling `Range` within the Sheet module defaults to `Me.Range`, thus using *that* worksheet.

I believe the following accomplishes what you need, without duplication:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    '   Target is already a range, no need to get the address explicitly
    If (Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("F1:F251")) Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim master As Worksheet: Set master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterRecord")
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sheets As Variant: sheets = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    Dim sheet As Variant

    master.Cells.ClearContents

    For Each sheet In sheets
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet)
        ws.Range("A2:G251").Copy
        master.Range("A" & master.Range("A" & master.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next

    Set master = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

### Edit

Looks like the only that needs to change if you want to have this happen on all Worksheets is placing it in the `Workbook_SheetChange` method in the `ThisWorkbook` module. Note that there is no longer Me.Range near the top, but rather Sh.Range. Since a worksheet is calling this method, I don't think it would make much of a difference using `Sh.Range` vs `Range`, but it never hurts.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

Most importantly, notice how I Disable Events if the condition is met (then enable them when the code is done). If you do not turn off events, each time you paste new data into the worksheet it will trigger the change event, which you don't want in this case.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("F1:F251")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        ' Copies contents A2:F251 from each monthly
        ' sheet to master record sheet.
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Dim wsMR As Worksheet
        Set wsMR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterRecord")

        wsMR.Cells.ClearContents

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            Select Case ws.Name


                 Case Is = "January", "February", "March", "April", _
                        "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", _
                        "October", "November", "December"

                    Dim NextRow As Long
                    NextRow = wsMR.Range("A" & wsMR.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    ws.Range("A2:G251").Copy
                    wsMR.Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                End Select
        Next

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is throwing a Type Mismatch error at the .Row + 1

Comment: thanks, that cleared the compile error.  However, now nothing is copying at all, either properly or in a loop. I changed a value in F29 of sheet February and no data was copied to the sheet MasterRecord

Comment: Did you put this code in the sheet for `February`? Do you want the data for every *month* sheet to copy to the MasterRecord sheet when you change `F1:F251` of any of the *month* sheets? Because that is a different method for that. Also, I edited the `Case Is = ` statement.

Comment: Scott raises a good question. If you anticipate that all months need this functionality, you will need to move and modify the method slightly. The alternate approach is to put this in each Sheet module which is completely unnecessary duplication.

Comment: @scott-holtzman - Yes, the code is in the `February` sheet module.  My intention was to put the code in each monthly sheet module so that anytime a value in `F1:F251` is changed in _any_ monthly sheet, the `A2:G251` data of _every_ monthly sheet is copied to `MasterRecord` so that `MasterRecord` always has an accurate copy of all data in the monthly sheets.  If I remove only the Case statement and definitions and place it in `MasterRecord` the code copies correctly when run manually through the VBA interface.

Comment: @rkent Take a look at my answer, I have tested it and believe it accomplishes what you're looking for, with an explanation as to why your first attempt wasn't working.

Comment: @rkent - yes, I would have changed my answer based on your last comment, but it looks you got what you need from Tyler. :)